# iPhone: How to make UIButton which you can easily tap?

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uibutton

I'm making customized navigation bar by using `UIView` and `UIButtons` instead of `UINavigationBar`.

But my `UIButtons` on the navigation bar doesn't response sensitively.

I have to tap almost center of the `UIButton` to tap.
It doesn't respond if I tap edge of the `UIButton`.

But buttons on normal `UINavigationBar` can be tapped by tapping edge of the button.
Even by tapping outside of the button, it can be tapped.

Shutter button or Option button on the camera app also can be tapped by tapping edge or outside of buttons.

How can I implement those easily tappable buttons to my app?

Comment: some sample code might help diagnose the problem.

Comment: @ben Thanks. I'll look for sample code.
But this is not my problem. I think this is specification of `UIButton`.
All `UIButton` are less sensitive than `UINavigationBar`'s button.
I want to know some property or way to expand region which can be tapped.

Comment: UIButton generally has a very large tap area. It is likely you're misconfiguring them rather than them being broken and you needing to work around it. Ben's request for code is correct.

Comment: @Rob not very large. Please tap and compare UIButton and navigation bar button of sample code, for example, `UICatalog` or `AddMusic` with real device not simulator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use an image and create a custom button.  Set the button so the image does not scale to the size of the button's view, but instead will just Center.  Expand the button's size so it is larger than the image on each side.  Apple does this as well with things like tab buttons.

Comment: Just to clarify, the actual size of the button is bigger than the image it displays, so the touchable area is a lot larger than just the image size, though since only the image appears, a lot larger area is touch sensitive.

Comment: thanks! it works. i found UIButton's inset property is also useful to expand tap area. And adding transparent margin to image also can expand tap area.

Answer (score 10):

`UIButton` has an [`imageEdgeInsets` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/imageEdgeInsets) specially for this purpose. Just make a UIButton frame as big as you need for touchable area and than scale image inside it appropriately, using `imageEdgeInsets`.

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer:** *This code has not been tested, but it gives you an idea of how it could be done.*

You make a button (in this case 40px x 40px), and then add a background image to it which is smaller, hence gives the impression of that the image is very "clickable".

```
// This image is 20px x 20px (Just an example)
UIImage* backgroundImage = UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImage.png"]

// Custom button, remember to add a target method
UIButton* customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
customButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
customButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
[customButton setImage:backgroundImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIBarButtonItem* customBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customBarButtonItem;
[customBarButtonItem release];
```